# When someone asks the same question over and over

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

What is the term when someone asks the same question over and over because he is trolling.

Spamming might work, but I would like a *more formal* word.

> I got mad because he was ...

Comment: **Spamming** if your audience is young enough.

Comment: @TsSkTo thanks, but I would like a little more formal word

Comment: Hmm. **Pleonastic**? https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pleonasm

Comment: Nope thats not what I wanted @TsSkTo

Comment: I reformatted your text and added the SWR tag. If you are not happy with the revisions, feel free to roll them back. SWR tags are apt to draw fire from some users on principle. PS We usually do not use code formatting ( I guess it is called) to block text.

Comment: What is the situation? Did he repetitively ask the same question because he has Alzheimer's? Because you didn't answer it correctly? Because he's trying to make sure you know he is ignoring your answers? Can you please update the post with more situational detail?

Comment: Because he is trolling @hank

Comment: Can you add that to the OP, please? Some people will not look at comments for clarification and your post may end up being closed for that.

Comment: @Hank I did it.Hope my question will be less nebulous

Comment: I do think **spamming** or **nagging** is a fit here.

Comment: I *still* don't understand the context. *Trolling* means *sowing discord on the Internet by starting arguments or upsetting people, by posting inflammatory, extraneous, or off-topic messages in an online community*. But I don't really see how you can do that successfully by simply asking the same question over and over (presumably, without taking any notice of any actual *answers* you might be given). Unless the actual question is ***Why?***, which as children we soon learn can be asked recursively no matter what answer you're given (and there might actually *be* a word for *that!* :)

Comment: I would stick with Troll as I think it means something very specific and the other good words mean fine things but don't capture the mischievous yet purposeful malice as well as each word evoking a different flavor of discomfort.

Comment: I've told someone the truth about a matter but he refuse to believe me. He been asking me the same questions over an over for 4 months. Its stressing me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nagging](https://www.google.com/search?q=nagging%20synonym&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=NlZtWJnQA8LR8Aex1ZuQBg)

which means  to annoy or irritate somebody with constant urging.

It is often used to indicate constant complaining, but it works here.

Synonyms include:

> harass, badger, give someone a hard time, hound, harry, criticize, carp, find fault with, keep on at, grumble at, go on at;

**I got mad because he was nagging/badgering/harrassing me.**

Comment: @user213640 On sites like this, we usually refer to it as "harrasment" when it is of a personal nature.

Comment: "nagging": it carries with it heavy gender-stereotypes (certainly using it to describe a even a 'trolling' line of questions by a woman congressperson would be considered sexist). Also, 'nagging' is frequently used while advocating reasonable/beneficial expectations, where a troll is bringing up unreasonable things with an intent to provoke.  'badgering', rings to me as forcing war of attrition, not reason, while advocating for a point held in good faith. Harassment rings more as an ad hominem attack ...  and trolling can be quite malicious and disruptive without getting personal.

Answer (score 6):

[**Pester**:](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pester)

To behave in an annoying manner towards someone by doing or asking for something repeatedly.

> John has been pestering her to go out with him all month. (Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: Somoene pesting usually wants to actually get something done and it's not infrequently used when they're pestering about a valid concern.  Trolling is meant to disrupt, and to create anger and chaos,  not to get a concern frequently held in good faith dealt with. (frequently: 'stop pestering me, I'll get around to it')